# Calcular una mano y hacer un contador de valores de esta en una baraja de 52 cartas

Tags: python

Necesito crear una función para crear la baraja en la que los palos van enumerados del 1 al 4 y el valor de las cartas del 1 al 13, otra función para sacar aleatoriamente una mano de 5 cartas y finalmente una función que, mediante una lista, cuente las veces que aparecen los valores de mi mano, por ejemplo, si tengo un as, tres 9 y un 12 tendría que obtener algo así: [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,1]. Este es mi código:

```
import random

def Baraja (palos, valores):
    baraja = []
    for a in range (1, palos+1):
        for b in range (1, valores+1):
            dato = [a,b]
            baraja.append (dato)
    return (baraja)

def Mano (baraja, cartas_mano):
    mano = []
    carta = 0
    if (carta < cartas_mano):
        carta += 1
        aleatorio = random.randint (0, len(baraja)-1)
        carta = baraja [aleatorio]
        while (carta in mano):
            aleatorio = random.randint (0, len(baraja)-1)
            carta = baraja [aleatorio]
    mano.append(carta)
    return (carta)

def ContadorValoresMano (mano, valores):
    lista_contadores = [0] * valores
    for a in range (valores):
        if a in lista_contadores:
            lista_contadores [a] += 1
    return lista_contadores

palos = 4
valores = 13
cartas_mano = 5
baraja = Baraja(palos, valores)
print ("Baraja",baraja)
mano = Mano (baraja,cartas_mano)
print ("Mano",mano)
contador_valores = ContadorValoresMano(mano, valores)
print ("Valores",contador_valores)
```

El problema es que en la función Mano solo consigo que me saque una carta en vez de cinco y en la de ContadorValoresMano no consigo que me cuente los valores que ya me han salido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu código en formato código y no en una imagen? Para algo está esa opción, para que podamos copiar y pegar el código en nuestras máquinas para probarlo. Me niego a copiar tu código a mano. Pulsa en "editar", quita la imagen, y añade y código en el formato correcto para que podamos ayudarte ;)

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado, lo siento, no sabía que podía hacer eso

Comment: *El problema es que en la función Mano solo consigo que me saque una carta en vez de cinco* -> En ningún momento haces que saque 5, solo sacas una y repites en bucle si te ha dado una repetida. El primer `if` de esa función, debería ser un bucle. Además, la línea `mano.append(carta)` debería estar *DENTRO* del bucle, no fuera como está ahora

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algunos errores en tu código.

## Errores

- return (carta) en la función Mano, cuando deberías retornar la mano.
- usar la variable carta en dicha función para múltiples tareas (contar cantidad de cartas y guardar el objeto de la carta)
- recorrer dos bucles en ContadorValoresMano, con solo recorrer tu  mano e ir registrando los valores alcanza.
- mano.append(carta) está indentado fuera del bucle generador de cartas, debería estar dentro del mismo para ir adicionando las cartas generadas.

## Código funcionando

```
import random

def Baraja (palos, valores):
    baraja = []
    for a in range (1, palos+1):
        for b in range (1, valores+1):
            dato = [a,b]
            baraja.append (dato)
    return (baraja)

def Mano (baraja, cartas_mano):
    mano = []
    cantidad_cartas = 0
    while (cantidad_cartas < cartas_mano):
        cantidad_cartas += 1
        aleatorio = random.randint (0, len(baraja)-1)
        carta = baraja [aleatorio]
        while carta in mano: # Para evitar repetir cartas
            aleatorio = random.randint (0, len(baraja)-1)
            carta = baraja [aleatorio]
        mano.append(carta)
    return (mano)

def ContadorValoresMano (mano, valores):
    lista_contadores = [0] * valores
    for carta in mano:
        lista_contadores [carta[0]-1] += 1
    return lista_contadores

palos = 4
valores = 13
cartas_mano = 5
baraja = Baraja(palos, valores)
print ("Baraja",baraja)
mano = Mano (baraja,cartas_mano)
print ("Mano",mano)
contador_valores = ContadorValoresMano(mano, valores)
print ("Valores",contador_valores)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando juegas con una baraja tienes varias listas:

- Baraja: El total de las cartas del juego
- Mazo: Las cartas que aún no
  has repartido. Incluso puede tener varias barajas.
- Mano: Las cartas
  que tiene cada jugador en su poder.

Al inicio del juego todas las cartas de la **Baraja** están en el **Mazo**.
Cada vez que das una carta a un jugador la eliminas del **Mazo** y así no la volverás a dar.

`random.choice(lista)` elige un valor entre los de la lista.

```
def Baraja (palos, valores):    #Creas una baraja
    baraja = []
    for a in range (1, palos+1):
        for b in range (1, valores+1):
            dato = [a,b]
            baraja.append (dato)
    return (baraja)

def Mano (mazo, cartas_mano):
    mi_mano = []
    for _ in range(cartas_mano):
        carta = random.choice(mazo)  #   Tomas una carta
        mazo.remove(carta)  #   Eliminas la carta del mazo
        mi_mano.append(carta)   #   Añades una carta a la mano del jugador

    return (mazo, mi_mano)  #   Devuelves lo que queda en el mazo y las cartas del jugador

def ContadorValoresMano (mano, valores):
    lista_contadores = [0] * valores
    for carta in mano:
        lista_contadores[carta[0]-1] += 1
    return lista_contadores

palos = 4
valores = 13
cartas_mano = 5
baraja = Baraja(palos, valores)
#   print ("Baraja",baraja)
mazo = baraja.copy()    #   Pasas toda la baraja al mazo de dar

mazo, mi_mano = Mano(mazo, cartas_mano) #   Recibes las cartas que quedan en el mazo y la mano que das.
print ("Mano",mi_mano)
contador_valores = ContadorValoresMano(mi_mano, valores)
print ("Valores",contador_valores)
```